# How to stretch input field to full width?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML form.  I'd like the right widgets in the second column (text field, combox, and so on) to stretch and fill the full column.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="formTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">Report Number</td>
    <td class="col2"><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">Report Type</td>
    <td class="col2"><select></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.formTable {
  border-color: black;
}

.formTable td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.formTable .col1 {
  text-align: right;
}

.formTable .col2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget the close tag of the second cell in the first column. :-)

Comment: I think everybody had the answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can specify that all of the children of class "col2" have a width of 100% by adding the following:

```
.col2 * { width:100%;}
```

See my dabblet example: http://dabblet.com/gist/2227353

Answer (score 8):

Start with semantic markup since this isn't tabular data. Also, with added labels, we don't need extra wrapper DIVs, which is cleaner.

```
<ul class="formList">
    <li>
        <label for="input_1">
            Report Number
        </label>
        <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="input_2">
            Report Type
        </label>
        <select id="input_2" name="input_2"></select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then add the CSS:

```
.formList {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
label {
    width:200px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    float:left;
}
input, select {
    width:100%;
}
li {
    padding-left:200px;
}
```

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6EyGK/

Comment: It is a set of field/value pairs with no headings and added user input. That isn't tabular.

Comment: In this WhatWG spec (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) it says: `The table element represents data with more than one dimension, in the form of a table.` key/value pairs are two dimensional, so table is ok for me.

Comment: On that same page it says "Tables must not be used as layout aids." Wouldn't using tables to align a label next to an input constitute as controlling page layout instead of properly semantic code?

Comment: I think layout is meant as 'page layout' which means the layout of the *whole* page and not just laying out data in a section of the page.

Comment: This works nicely except for one thing: you lose the vertical baseline alignment between label and input. Any solution that works along these lines, but also preserves that baseline alignment?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
.col2 * {
    width: 100%;
}
```

To match any `.col2` descendant. as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/9W5M6/). Or:

```
.col2 > * {
    width: 100%;
}
```

To match just the immediate children.

Answer (score 2):

if using Twitter **Bootstrap**:
and input is inside a column

just add to `<input>` the `class="container-fluid"`

Comment: There is no `bootstrap` tag, so the OP doesn't use bootstrap.

Comment: No way to tell from a code snippet if bootstrap is being used or not. If there was a bootstrap tag, it is no longer required. This might answer the question, per stated condition. And it was helpful for me.

Comment: note: while using bootstrap, width: 100% did not work for me.

Comment: using bootstrap, setting width:100% does not work idd, setting container-fluid does

Answer (score 0):

### Note

This is not an answer, but a comment, which includes too much code to go into the comment section. So please refrain from downvoting me, would you? :)

Other semantic markup additionaly to Matthew Darnells answer:

If you wrap the labels around the inputs and selects, you can avoid using the `for`and `id` attributes.

```
<ul class="formList">
    <li>
        <label>
            Report Number
        <input name="input_1" type="text" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            Report Type
        <select name="input_2"></select>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or use a definition list which might give you additional control

```
<dl class="formList">
    <dt>
        <label for="input_1">
            Report Number
        </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" />
    </dd>
    <dt>
        <label for="input_2">
            Report Type
        </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <select id="input_2" name="input_2"></select>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: Whoever donwvoted this, could at least leave a comment with some reasoning

Comment: Not sure who down voted, but your answer doesn't answer the question in any way.