# Expand the input box TextField to fullWidth when selected in Material UI with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm working on a Material UI form where the input box ([Text Field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field)) is 200px wide on load.

I want to make the input box expand to 100% width only when the box is selected or clicked on.

```js
...
<FormGroup sx={{ maxWidth: "200px" }}>
        <FormControl>
          <TextField
            id="first_name"
            label="First name" />
        </FormControl>
</FormGroup> 
...
```

I'm looking to doing something like [How to stretch input field to full width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910790/how-to-stretch-input-field-to-full-width) but with Material UI.

I've tried using an `onClick` attribute on `TextField` but that did not action register an event on click.

I know there's a `fullWidth` attribute for `TextField` but I'm just not sure how to go about changing the attribute on click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove width from `FormGroup` and add inside `TextField` then override css class with 100% width. You can also add `transition` property if you want to  increase the width smoothly than instant.

```
...
<FormGroup>
  <FormControl>
    <TextField
      sx={{
        width: 200,
        '&:focus-within':{
          width:'100%',
        },
        transition: 'width 1s',
      }}
      id="first_name"
      label="First name"
    />
  </FormControl>
</FormGroup> 
...
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Now I know how to change the CSS dynamically!